# Java modules - use code from one module in tests implementation in another module

Tags: gradle, java-11

I set up a project with Java 11, Spring Boot and Gradle with Kotlin DSL. I use also `org.javamodularity.moduleplugin`.

I have three modules in my project: module1 (main code of application), module2 (library for common clases for implementation) and module3 (library for commons classes needed for test implementation). Module1 doesn't see module3, which I use in tests implementation.

I added module-info files to modules and dependencies in Gradle files. Everything works perfectly when I use module2 in module1. Module1 sees and reads all classes from module2.
I did the same to make visible module3 for module1. Unluckily, it doesn't work.

module-info for module1:

```
module module1 {
    requires module2;
   //requires module3; <-not working
}
```

build.gradle.kts for module1:

```
   implementation(project(":module2"))
   testImplementation(project(":module3"))
```

module-info for module3:

```
module module3 {
    exports module3.mypackage;
}
```

settings.gradle.kts:

```
include("module1", "module2", "module3")
```

After run tests in Gradle, I get the error:
`error: package module3.mypackage is not visible` and `(package module3.mypackage is declared in module module3, but module module1 does not read it)`

When I uncomment line `requires module3;` I get:
`error: module not found: module3`

What did I miss?
What should I do to run the code from module3 in module1 tests implementation?